# guardar en variables int, String y boolean lo obtenido por el ResultSet

Tags: java, base-de-datos, string, booleano, integer

Tengo un `Object [][]`donde guardo temporalmente tres valores que obtengo de la `Base de Datos`, un `int`, un `String` y un `boolean`, cómo hago para pasarlos de:

```
result.next();{

    datosObt[0][0] = result.getString( "cedula" );
    System.out.println("Ususario BD: "+ datosObt[0][0]);
    datosObt[0][1] = result.getString( "password" );
    System.out.println("PWD BD: "+ datosObt[0][1]);
    datosObt[0][2] = result.getString( "tipo" );
    System.out.println("Tipo BD: "+ datosObt[0][2]);
}
    result.close();
```

a variables separadas por cada tipo, ejemplo

```
int documento;
String contrasenia;
boolean admin;
```

Estoy 100% perdido, busqué y de los métodos que he visto ninguno me funcionó, actualmente borré todo y no tengo nada de los intentos de transformarlos.

Answer (score 1):

Se puede lograr convertir con los métodos siguientes.

```
int documento= Integer.parseInt(datosObt[0][0].toString());
String contrasenia = datosObt[0][1].toString();
boolean admin= Boolean.parseBoolean(datosObt[0][2].toString());
```

Comment: `Para el int me dice:` El método parseInt(String) que hay en el tipo Integer no es aplicable para los argumentos (Object).                 `Para el String me dice:` Discrepancia de tipos: no se puede convertir de Object a String.                `Para el booleano me dice:` El método parseBoolean(String) que hay en el tipo Boolean no es aplicable para los argumentos (Object)

Comment: eso es por que le estas pasando un objeto y no un string. `datosObt` debe ser de tipo `Object`, eso no lo especificas en tu pregunta. puedes usar el método `.toString()` que devuelve la representacion en forma de string de un objeto.

Comment: Ahora si. era lo que faltaba. Muchas Gracias!!!

Comment: Si te ha servido favor de marcar como aceptada la respuesta